# How to rename a child directory in Java?

Tags: java, file

How can I rename a directory in java .
I have a directory structure like /workspace/project-name/project/user/wbench/test/<multiple folders & git objects>

In the above structure I want to change test to dev (for example).

I thought Files.renameTo() will do the trick for me but this code is not working.

```
public ResponseMessage updateDirectoryName(String oldDirectoryName, String newDirectoryName, String userName) {
   File projectDirectoryForUser = gitUtils.getProjectDirectoryFromRepoName(userName, oldDirectoryName);

    try {
        if (projectDirectoryForUser.exists()) {
            File newDir = new File(projectDirectoryForUser.getParent()+File.separator+newDirectoryName);
            Boolean flag =projectDirectoryForUser.renameTo(newDir);
            if(flag){
                System.out.println("File renamed successfully");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Rename operation failed");
            }
        }
        else {
            log.info("No folder found for Project in file path");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        log.info("something is not right" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

My flag is always false and name of directory is not changed.
I am certainly doing something wrong not sure what?

Comment: According to my test (Windows 10 and JDK 17.0.2), if directory `test` has subdirectories, the _rename_ operation will fail. It succeeds if `test` only contains regular files. (Refer to method `isFile` in class `java.io.File`)

Comment: Ok I think thats the issue , but test can contain subdirectories and other objects , so how can test be renamed

Comment: Create a new directory and perform a copy instead of a move. After the copy you can delete the source directory.

Comment: Use [Files.move](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) instead of the ancient File.renameTo method.  Files.move may or may not cause the operation to work, but it will provide you with an informative exception explaining why it failed, which is much better than a simple boolean value.  And I strongly recommend printing `e` rather than e.getMessage().  Exception messages by themselves are rarely informative.

Comment: @VGR did you try it? For me it gives `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` which basically means that the operation cannot be performed.

Comment: @Abra Exactly my point.  As I said:  It may or may not cause the operation to work, but it will provide much more information than an opaque, obscure boolean value provides.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getParent()` must be `getParentFile()` so you have the full path.

The newer generalisation of `File`, the class `Path`, together with the utilities class `Files` one should better use. [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) is the equivalent of a `File.renameTo` and *might not in every case work for non-empty directories.*

```
public ResponseMessage updateDirectoryName(String oldDirectoryName,
        String newDirectoryName, String userName) {
    Path projectDirectoryForUser = gitUtils.getProjectDirectoryFromRepoName(userName,
            oldDirectoryName).toPath();

    try {
        if (Files.exists(projectDirectoryForUser)) {
            Path newDir = projectDirectoryForUser.resolveSibling(newDirectoryName);
            Files.move(projectDirectoryForUser, newDir);
            boolean flag = Files.exist(newDir);
            if (flag) {
                System.out.println("File renamed successfully");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Rename operation failed");
            }
        } else {
            log.info("No folder found for Project in file path");
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        log.info("something is not right" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Whereas `File` is a disk file, `Path` can also be from an URI, or a packed "file" in a zip file. Different file system views. This allows `File` to copy file or java resource into a zip, or rename a file in a zip.
So for the same reason one uses `List` instead of an implementing `ArrayList`, one better use `Path`. Also I read that the `Files` operations are a bit better than those of `File`.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change a value os a final variable. Remove the "final" keyword from "projectDirectoryForUser" and try again.

[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_keyword_final.asp)

Comment: while copying I had missed removing final , but no luck

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).